# Does GDAL support parallel processing?

Tags: gdal, parallel-processing

I would like to speed up the process corresponding to this command:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -overwrite input.ntf output.tif`

Is there a way to use parallel processing in GDAL?
Semi-offtopic: If not, do you recommend a non-GDAL solution to speeding up a gdalwarp-like process?

Here are the web pages I've looked at:

- [Is it possible to do parallel processing in GDAL and QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178605/is-it-possible-to-do-parallel-processing-in-gdal-and-qgis)
- [[gdal-dev] GDAL raster processing: parallel computing](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-GDAL-raster-processing-parallel-computing-td5281059.html)

Edit: I asked this question because I thought I saw my CPU% stay below 100% when processing gdalwarp. However, on a second look, it reached 555.5%.

Comment: Did you read about -multi in the document http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html?

Comment: `-multi` made it even faster. The max CPU% I saw was 700% instead of 555%. The process took 22 seconds instead of 32 seconds.

Answer (score 15):

**Yes**, GDAL supports parallel processing, and this support applies to gdalwarp by default.

**Use the -multi option** with gdalwarp to enable multithreading, as opposed to only multiple cores.

Details:

Without -multi:
33.849s, and the CPU reached 555%. (multiple cores)

With -multi:
23.377s, and the CPU reached 700%. (multiple cores and multiple threads)

Raster size: 34721 x 20453, OS: Ubuntu 16.04, # Cores: 6, # Threads: 12

---

Credit: [user30184](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/30184/user30184) mentioned the `-multi` option in a comment.

Documentation: [gdalwarp](http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html)

Comment: See the improved documentation (by https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/changeset/38196) of gdalwarp `-multi:
    Use multithreaded warping implementation. Two threads will be used to process chunks of image and perform input/output operation simultaneously. Note that computation is not multithreaded itself. To do that, you can use the -wo NUM_THREADS=val/ALL_CPUS option, which can be combined with -multi`. See also http://www.gdal.org/structGDALWarpOptions.html#a0ed77f9917bb96c7a9aabd73d4d06e08

Comment: Does this work with gdal_rasterize?