# QGIS only using one core

Tags: qgis, merge, performance

I am using QGIS 3.24.2 Tisler. Machine is an i9-7900 @3.30 Ghz 64 GB RAM using Windows 11 64bit. Disk is SSD and Gfx card is a RTX2060he

When doing a raster merge (Raster - misc  - merge) of multiple asc files QGIS is only using a single logical core. I can see that core being maxed out with all the other 19 sitting there idle. Disk I/O is minimal and GFX card utilisation is again minimal. Memory utilisation is about 15%

In options I have Render layers in parallel using many CPU cores enabled.

Is the merge a single core operation or should it be using multiple cores? If the latter any idea whay it isn't doing so?

Comment: Raster rendering has nothing to do with GDAL libraries. https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#merge

Comment: So does that mean that waht i am attempting to do is a single core activity or is it possible to have it use multiple cores? If it is how?

Comment: This means that you need to find out if the GDAL library supports multiple processors for data processing.

Comment: I am not being deliberately obtuse here but i have no idea what you are talking about. the link you provided is no help at all without some context. does the operation i am doing have multi core support, or is it a singe core operation? if it depends on a setting or a particular configuiration what is that setting?

Answer (score 1):

One of the GDAL tools (gdalwarp) supports multiprocessing: [Does GDAL support parallel processing?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239101/does-gdal-support-parallel-processing).

To use it as described [here](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html), you must use the `-multi` keyword.

It seems merge tool does not support multiprocessing because there is no such option in the [merge](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_merge.html) tool description.